# What's meaning of '#programmed' attribute of a form array in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-fapi

What's meaning of '#programmed' attribute of a form array in drupal?
I didn't find any documentation for it in drupal.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal allows you to submit forms from a programmatically, which can be really useful for making comments/nodes etc from a custom module. '#programmed' is set to true when a form is submitted by a function using drupal_execute. see more here: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_execute/6

Comment: Thanks.Can you provide a link to it's(and other form attributes) documentation page?

Comment: I am not aware of and cannot find anything specifically documenting the #programmed attribute, but its just a boolean value which is true when a form is submitted with drupal_execute. The holy grail of the forms api is here though: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6